# Partial path match regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to develop a regex that partially matches a certain branch of a path. Not before and not deeper than that level. For example:

```
/path  - no match
/path/subpath - no match
/path/subpath/XYZ-123/subpath - no match
/path/subpath/XYZ-123 - match
```

So far, I have the following

```
^\/path\/subpath\/.*$
```

However, this obviously also matches for `/path/subpath/XYZ-123/subpath` which I would like to exclude as well. Note that the path contains characters, numbers and special characters.

Comment: `^\/path\/subpath\/[^\/]*$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\/path\/subpath\/[^\/]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xHiuL5/1/).

The regex will match

- `^` - start of a string
- `\/path\/subpath\/` - `/path/subpath/` string
- `[^\/]*` - 0 or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.